# Running multiple Python scripts in Aptana 3

Tags: python, aptana

If I run two different Python scripts simultaneously, I see a console window which shows output from each of the scripts alternately, switching back and forth every second or so. If I open a second console window before running the second script, the same thing happens - both console windows switch between the 2 scripts.

How can I get each script to output to its own console window?

Comment: Why don't you just run the scripts from the command line, one terminal per script? Is that not an option?

Comment: I run scripts in Aptana for convenience and, at the moment, running scripts in the command line doesn't work - paths and library modules are not found.

Comment: Has no-one else ever run 2 simultaneous scipts in Aptana?

Answer (score 1):

a very belated response but it sounds like your issue is that you have the 'Show Console When Standard Out Changes' option selected.

Hope that helps, or that you found the solution on your own. Cheers!